# PhpStorm save external changes not always triggered

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm as my IDE for a while now. I've always been working with the option to upload changes on explicit save (using CMD+S). But lately I've started fiddling around with SCSS and a file watcher to automatically parse the SCSS file. In order to also upload the newly parsed CSS file after I made a change in the SCSS file I've checked the option `Upload external changes`.

I've noticed not always the file is uploaded after the SCSS has parsed and it takes me two times to save the SCSSS (add another blank space or something to make a change).

I think there might be two reasons:

1. The Upload external changes isn't working properly
2. The above is untrue but the file watcher is still working and the file was uploaded already. It should be configured to first let the file watcher complete and then upload.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Show your file watcher settings.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Since I've been watching the behavior I've noticed I maybe have to let the file watcher complete first and then save. If I wait a little longer there's no problem. Is there a setting to queue the upload if the file watcher completes?

Comment: So .. it creates `.css` file next to the `.scss` one, right? For whatever reason IDE does not pick up changes in compiled files (does not see them) hence it's still marked as "old/valid". Instead of second run of file watcher .. you may try `File | Synchronize` -- it will force re-read of project files looking for changes. You may also try to untick `Immediate file synch` in file watcher settings -- this way file watcher will only be run when you actually saving a file and not automatically after small delay after each key press (should help if you have delays/takes time to compile)

Comment: But on a grand scale -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410 (see if today's 9.0.2 makes any changes here; ticket status is "reopened" so not yet properly fixed, but maybe the code that was already written is available and may do the job in your case)